# Too strict permissions checking in Mac OS

Tags: macos, unix, ssh

After long debugging, I found why I can not login to my MacOS machine with ssh:

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /Users/myuser/projects
```

The problem is that I track my `.ssh` config directory in a git repo, and I link to it in my home directory. It seems that MacOS, as opposed to Linux, does check that all parent directories *of the linked repo* have strict permissions. And this even though the repo itself has the right permissions:

```
» ls -ld /home/myuser/projects/homedir/dotfiles/.ssh
drwx------ 2 myuser myuser 4096 Feb 14 07:47 /home/myuser/projects/homedir/dotfiles/.ssh
```

Is it possible to disable this checking in MacOS? I have a single directory structure which I rsync around to my machines, and having to change this because of this MacOs limitation is a pain.

Comment: If any of the higher level directories are writable by other users than your own, I think macos has the right approach here. For changes in those directories may well have the side effect of changing the target of the symlink. If they're merely readable and/or executable by other users, that seems unnecessarily strict. You might be able to set up a hook to copy the files into a proper `~/.ssh` directory on a `git pull`, though?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen probably you are right, that permissions should be only read for group, even for parent directories. The question is then why does linux do not behave the same way?

Comment: On Linux, the check is the same. It is [in OpenSSH](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2f2ffa4fbe4b671bbffa0611f15ba44cff64d58e/auth.c#L528).